# TensorFlow Lite C++ API for RaspberryPI 4

Tags: c++, cmake, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, tensorflow-lite

I have to build a program running on Raspberry PI that uses TensorFlow Lite to run inference. The program must be written in C++, so I have to build TensorFlow Lite C++ API from source. I am referring to official documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake_arm?hl=en) but in any case there is always something going wrong with both Bazel and CMake.

In particular on Ubuntu 22.04 at some point the build (Step 5) failed and I discovered it happened because of an old version of g++. On Debian 12 the machine completely blocked and I had to shutting down by pressing on/off button. With Bazel on Ubuntu 22.04 the process looks like will never end. The machine I am using for cross-compilation has 6/12 cores and 16 GB RAM, so a decent amount of physical resources. Someone has any suggestion?

Comment: How many cores are being used when it it building?  Have you tried using the -j parameter to give it more cores?  When I cross compile it can take a long time on some of my projects, even with 32GB and 4 cores.

Comment: I switched to Windows11 compiling with WSL Ubuntu 22.04 and I succeded. Using -j in cmake resulted in some errors that some people on internet said to be caused by too much cores using all the memory. I tried -j4 and I successfully built it in a decent amount of time. But still at the end something did not work because I could not built label_image example (error was missing reference to a function). At the end with this new setting (Win11 + WSL) I built it with Bazel and it seems to work. My machine has 6 physical cores, 12 threads and 16Gb RAM. I still have to try not trivial examples tough.